# AppleScript FTW? Ignoring .doc headers in batch conversion

Tags: applescript, docx

I have to batch convert a bunch of .doc files to txt. Problem is they have headers in them, and neither textutils in mac nor wvText nor catdox have options for ignoring the headers of .doc and .dox

So as much as I would love to spend my day understanding microsoft's proprietary document format, I found that pages ignored the header when I exported doc and docx files. So now im trying to get this done for hundreds of files in apple script.

```
tell application "Pages"
    activate
    export "Downloads/2spkr.doc" to "~/Downloads/2spkr.txt" as "txt"
end tell
```

And then apple script says no comprendo and shuts down. Does anyone out there still use applescript?

Comment: Why not use something like Apache Tika?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. People/companies use AppleScript. Using Pages v5.2 on OSX 10.9.4, I can do the following with no problem:

```
tell application "Finder" to set dt to desktop as string
tell application "Pages"
    set doc to document 1
    export doc to file (dt & "foo.txt") as unformatted text
end tell
```

See http://iworkautomation.com/pages/document-export.html

(Also wondering if you've opened the document in TextEdit, which (with some limitations) can also open .doc files, so you can do `save doc in file (dt & "foo.txt")` with similar results -- but I'm not sure about the header issue.)

**[edit]**
also, see http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/20/batch-convert-docx-to-txt-mac/ (untested, don't know how textutil does with the header stuff)

Comment: Incidentally, I see a lot of the '/' vs. ':' mistake. AppleScript uses ":" for the file path separator ("HD:folder:path:file.xxx") whereas the shell uses "/" ("/folder/path/file.xxx"). You can 'translate' between using `POSIX path of` and `POSIX file` in AS.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/hh181053%28v=office.15%29.aspx openXML has a function that accomplishes this. I'll report back on results.